# Chrome Extension: Open dev tools Panel Onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, chrome-app-developer-tool

I am using the chrome extension API  `chrome.devtools.panels.create` to create a dev tool panel.

```
``chrome.devtools.panels.create("My Console", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/browser-logos/63.0.0/chromium/chromium_48x48.png", "panel.html",
    function (panel) { console.log("hello world"); });
```

})``

But I want to make the experience better by letting the user open the dev panel by clicking on the extension. So it can open like the inbuilt chrome inspect console.

I don't seem to see the reference on their API doc that can make me achieve this.

Please, who can help with this?

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: hmmn, really? And there is no work around?